# Angular 2 relative templateUrl not working

Tags: javascript, angular

Creating my first Angular 2 app I'm trying to set my template in an html file using templateUrl.

At the moment, I have the component.ts and the view.html in the same folder under src/ folder and I'm using this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'relative-path',
  templateUrl: 'view.html'
})
```

Once running the app the console say:

> zone.js:1274GET http://localhost:3000/personalData.html 404 (Not Found)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: try templateUrl: './view.html'

Comment: @rinukkusu I'm using webpack

Comment: @LDJ I've done it already and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'relative-path',
  template: require('view.html')
})
```

Comment: Could you give me your `presets` in `webpack.config.js`?. I have added require in my project. but I found another issue. I still cannot solve it.

Comment: Dude, this was 6 years ago xD. As you may imagine, I don't have it :D

Answer (score 3):

Set the `moduleId`, like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'relative-path',
  templateUrl: 'some.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['some.component.css']
})
```

For documentation, see [Component-relative Paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

Comment: I've made it already and I'm getting "moduleId should be a string"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are putting the same name as html file name?

Ex: file name is "myView.html"

in templateUrl: 'myView.html'

Comment: 100% sure and verified

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `./` and it will work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'relative-path',
  templateUrl: './view.html'
})
```

It's a lot easier to work with an absolute path and you will most likely never need a relative path when trying to find a template for a component if you follow the official style guide.

Comment: @ZanattMan Then something else is wrong. Can you provide a plunkr?